# Is there a way to limit the AWS lambda function URL to private instead of public?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-vpn

I am trying to invoke the lambda Function URL which should not be accessible from public internet and only be accessible if connected to AWS VPN.

Also, the built lambda Function URL is kept inside VPC with subnets and security groups.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112349/aws-lambda-function-via-function-url-invoke-only-within-vpc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AWS Lambda function via Function URL invoke only within VPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72112349/aws-lambda-function-via-function-url-invoke-only-within-vpc)

Comment: @Paolo, Thanks for your suggested post. I wanted to know how to make Lambda URLs internal-only?

Comment: That's exactly what the other question is about as well

Comment: There is no exact solution even in the post. So, it didn't answer my question

Comment: What do you mean by "lambda Function URL"? Please Edit your question to provide more detail about what you are wanting to do (with examples) and what your _specific_ problem is.